# How to do a count 2 columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, count

I have the following table

| cus_id | gov_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | Bob |
| 1 | bb | Bill |
| 1 | aa | James |
| 2 | cc | Sam |
| 3 | aa | Sarah |
| 1 | aa | Joe |
| 2 | cc | Nathan |

As you can see when the `cus_id=1` and `gov_id=aa` there are `3` duplicates, thus the count is 3. I want to count how many instances where the `cus_id` and `gov_id` are the same, as in the row.

When `cus_id=2` and `gov_id=cc` there are 2 duplicates. I want the output like this:

| cus_id | gov_id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | Bob | 3 |
| 1 | bb | Bill | 1 |
| 1 | aa | James | 3 |
| 2 | cc | Sam | 2 |
| 3 | aa | Sarah | 1 |
| 1 | aa | Joe | 3 |
| 2 | cc | Nathan | 2 |

I tried:

```
SELECT cus_id, gov_id, name, count(*) as count
FROM test_table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytics functions:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by cus_id, gov_id) as cnt
from t;
```